# Xampp security problems

Tags: security, phpmyadmin, xampp

Im trying to configure Xampp as I have done before and everything use to work.
Now, I am a bit concerned because even though I have set a password for my PhpMyadmin(exactly as I have done in the past), the system doesn't ask me to log in at anytime. What has changed?
Before I had to log in with username "root" and password and now it doesn't ask for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With phpMyAdmin, there are different means of authenticating ("[auth_types](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types)"). These are generally set in the configuration file, `config.inc.php`, using a line like [`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type).

Using `cookie` or `http` prompt the user for username and password when connecting; `config` means it's hardcoded in to the configuration file and you're automatically connected. The default in the official phpMyAdmin distribution is `cookie`, however it sounds like XAMPP makes it `config`. You should be able to change that simply by editing the `config.inc.php` file and changing (or adding) the line mentioned above..